# if I setState of returned data in side (Promise.all) the function, It causes an infinite loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, async-await, setstate

Once the promise.all is resolved, I want to setState of returned data to `results`, but currently not able to do so. `checkData` has the correct data that I need. how can I avoid infinite loop and just setState of returned data.

note: `results` will then be passed on to the child components

```
  getEndResult = async () => {
    const userId = await this.getUserId(userId);
    const userData = await this.getUserData(userId);

    const checkData = await Promise.all(userData.checks.map(check => {
    return check.checkIds.map((checkIds) => {
        return this.getUserCredits(userId ,checkIds)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => console.log(data))

            // Can't setState here - causes infinite loop
            // .then(data => this.setState({ results: data }))
        })
    }))

    // Can't setState here - causes infinite loop
    this.setState({ checkData: data }))
    console.log(checkData);
  }
```

calling it here which is in child component

```
case getUserDetails(Constants.CREDITSTATUS): {

  getEndResults(userId);

  modalBody = (
    <UserDetailsModal
      userDetails={jd}
      setForm={this.setForm}
      updateActivity={updateActivity}
      updateUser={updateUser}
      updateUserDetails={updateUserDetails}
    />
  );
  break;
}
```

passing down to child component

```
render() {

  return (
    <div>
      <Route
        exact
        render={() => {
          return (
            <Overview
              getRecommendationResult={this.getRecommendationResult}
            />
          );
        }}
      />
```

Comment: Where are you calling the getEndResult function? Can you add more code?

Comment: If you are not doing it yet, you should make that call inside `componentDidMount`, as stated in the Documentation: https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html#where-in-the-component-lifecycle-should-i-make-an-ajax-call

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling the getresult function from  `use-effect` function, this  will cause to re-render the component on each state value changes.
In case of use-effect function add dependency inside it to avoid running the function again and again.

Comment: Yes,  ´´´´useeffect´´´´ might be causing the infinite loop

Comment: No, not calling it in `componentDidMount` or using `useEffect`, however `getEndResult` is being passed down to child component using render. I wonder if that causes the issue. will share code

Comment: useEffect is an optimization, worst case its the same as without using it. I wouldn't blame useEffect lol. The issue is you are calling this request in the render cycle, and you are setting state which will cause a re-render. which is where the infinite loop is. You should be using `componentDidMount` or `useEffect` to fix the problem

Comment: @JohnRuddell I understand its being called in render cycle, but I am not sure how to exactly use componentDidMount in here. any code example or resource you could link in. TX

Comment: you haven't even posted a component, its hard to work off of what you've given. your `case` in the "child component" has no context, is that in a render? a random function? we dont know your setup. if you want a code example of `componentDidMount` a [simple google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=react+componentDidMount+make+api+request) returned [**this article**](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-fetching-data). Plenty of good data out there, I would recommend you read up on best practices for how to use React, where you want to make requests... etc.

Comment: @JohnRuddell Thnx mate, what I'm working on is bit complex, sure will sort it out and will take a look at that article.

Comment: Great! Hope it goes well! Happy coding :)

Comment: Got it working by removing function call from render.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try to create an Array to store the promises like:

```
let promises = []
userData.checks.map(check => {
  check.checkIds.map((checkIds) => {
    promises.push(this.getUserCredits(userId ,checkIds)
  }
}
const checkData = await Promise.all(promises).then((values) => {
  console.log(values);
});
```

Comment: returning data isn't the issues, its setting state, your solution work aswell but setting state again causes issues